# Storing the result of pointer subtraction

Tags: c++11, pointers, types, difference, std

Typically the result of pointer subtraction is supposed to be `std::ptrdiff_t`, which is a signed type. However:

> If an array is so large (greater than PTRDIFF_MAX elements, but less
>   than SIZE_MAX bytes), that the difference between two pointers may not
>   be representable as std::ptrdiff_t, the result of subtracting two such
>   pointers is undefined.

To prevent getting into the realm of undefined behaviour, is there another type that is legally (by terms of the standard's intentions, not by terms of specific/common implementations) capable of holding the result of a pointer subtraction operation without fear of overflow?

In particular, are there any guarantees that `std::size_t` or `std::uintptr_t` would be suitable for storing the result of such an operation without overflow, underflow or undefined behaviour (assuming that in the expression `a - b`, `a` is greater than `b` so as to prevent underflow)?

Comment: The expression `a - b` must have some type, at compile time. It can't be "`ptrdiff_t`if `a < b` or `a` is close enough to `b` so as not to overflow `ptrdiff_t`, and `size_t` otherwise" because the condition can only be evaluated at run time.

Comment: Interesting question. If `std::distance` [is supposed to](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) return "the number of hops from first to last", [is there a "bug" in libcxx](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/iterator#L582)?

Answer (score 2):

I am not a language lawyer, but I have two ingredients in mind which---in theory---allow to compute the "distance" of two suitable pointers.

1. count the number of hops between the pointers one by one
2. use `std::less` and friends in order to obtain [more guarantees on the total order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_equal) (GCC [does care](https://godbolt.org/g/FdcWeZ))

This helps *in theory* because incrementing one by one is way too inefficient. Note that the linear cost hurts most in those cases where `std::ptrdiff_t` is "not enough".

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>

#include <functional>

template<class T>
constexpr std::size_t generalized_distance(T* first, T* last) {
// prefer `std::less_equal(first, last)` over `first <= last` because
// > it yields a strict total order even if the built-in operator<= does not
// (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_equal)
  assert(std::less_equal{}(first, last));

  std::size_t number_of_hops = 0;
// `last` might be "one past the end" so let us be sure and increment one by one
  while(std::less{}(first, last)) {
    ++first;
    ++number_of_hops;
  }
  return number_of_hops;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that's going to help.  If there's a fundamental platform-based limit on pointer arithmetic, incrementing a pointer multiple times isn't likely to avoid that limit, which is what you're doing with `++first;`.

Comment: Counting the number of hops one by one when there's a possibility of this number being greater than `2^31` (let alone `2^63`) might be, shall we say, somewhat inefficient.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: My suggestion is not addressing a "fundamental platform-based limit on pointer arithmetic". I just try to show that you can compute a "distance" between two suitable pointers even if the value is not be representable as `std::ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: @Julius If the implementation prevents computing the difference between two pointers via subtraction, why do you assume you can compute that difference by repeatedly incrementing one of those pointers?  They're both doing the same fundamental arithmetic pointer operations on the same objects.  If incrementing until they're equal is valid, subtraction would be, too.  Yet the implementation already has a restriction making that subtraction invalid.  Your proposed method is fundamentally flawed on such an implementation and any result it generates is potentially completely invalid.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I can not follow your reasoning. In fact, I do not believe that "If incrementing until they're equal is valid, subtraction would be, too.". Instead, I believe the following: `last - first` is undefined if the number of hops is not representable as `std::ptrdiff_t`. This may happen due to the "lost" sign bit in `std::ptrdiff_t`. However, incrementing `first` until `first == last` can still be well defined.

Comment: @Julius The very definition of subtraction is literally the counting of the number of increments between X and Y.  If the subtraction is invalid, the counting of increments is invalid too.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I have just looked it up in the N4649 draft for C++17. There I find another [definition of pointer subtraction](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.add#5) than you describe: "[...] If the expressions `P` and `Q` point to, respectively, elements `x[i]` and `x[j]` of the same array object `x`, the expression `P - Q` has the value `i−j`; otherwise, the behavior is undefined. [ Note: If the value `i−j` is not in the range of representable values of type `std​::​ptrdiff_­t`, the behavior is undefined.  — end note ]"

Comment: @Julius And that says *Note: If the value i−j is not in the range of representable values of type std​::​ptrdiff_­t, the behavior is undefined.*  That's exactly what I've been saying - if there's some perverse implementation that where the subtraction of two pointers results in undefined behavior, you can't handwave that away by incrementing one pointer until it matches the other.  That's squarely in "Mathematicians and computer scientists hate this one trick!" territory.

Comment: @Andrew, `number_of_hops` isn't a `std::ptrdiff_t`, so the undefined overflow doesn't occur in this code.  That's the difference (sorry) between this function and subtraction.  It's a shame we can't legally add `PTRDIFF_MAX` at a time, to reduce the computation to a sane level...